# Product count difference on categories and attributes filter in layered navigation on category Page in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2

There is a problem with showing product count on category and attribute filter section on the category page. In the product listing page, we are enabled to show the out of stock products. And in listing toolbar section it showing correct product count. But in Layered navigation filter section for the category and attributes it showing product count without out of stock products.

Comment: We need to show all products count(out of stock + in stock) in layered navigation filters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you added some **custom conditions** for product collection, your custom conditions work fine for your product collection in the listing page but when you check for layered navigation in the left sidebar, You may have the wrong result for product collection.

[Reference Link](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/)